# User Notification: Custom Vibration pattern

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications, iphone-vibrate

Is it possible to create custom vibration pattern for the user notification alert? example, we can choose to have different audio for the user notification. Is it possible to have custom vibration pattern as well?

I mean do this programmatically on iOS using swift.

Answer (score 1):

For create custom vibrations in iOS. Use AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration and AudioServicesStopSystemSound.

**Heart Beat Vibration Example**

```
NSMutableDictionary* pulsePatternsDict = [@{} mutableCopy];
        NSMutableArray* pulsePatternsArray = [@[] mutableCopy];

        // beat for 100 times
        for (NSInteger i=0; i<100; i++){
            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(YES)]; // vibrate for 100ms
            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(100)];

            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(NO)];  //stop for 1200ms * 0.3
            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(1200*0.3)];

            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(YES)];  //vibrate for 100ms
            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(100)];

            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(NO)];    //stop for 1200ms * 0.5
            [pulsePatternsArray addObject:@(1200*0.5)];
        }

        [pulsePatternsDict setObject:pulsePatternsArray forKey:@"VibePattern"];
        [pulsePatternsDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1.0] forKey:@"Intensity"];

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, nil, pulsePatternsDict);
```

But only call this (AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration )  will make a vibration never stop. So I have to found some function to stop it.

The answer is `AudioServicesStopSystemSound`. It's also a private function in AudioToolbox framework.

The declaration of the function is like

```
void AudioServicesStopSystemSound(SystemSoundID inSystemSoundID)
```

**NOTE:** `AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration` is only available on iOS6

**There is currently no public available API in iOS 9 and iOS 9.1.**

And In **iOS 10** there's a new API called `UIFeedbackGenerator`. See this [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-generate-haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_101) for more details. It only works on the iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus for now.

**Disclaimer:** There is a way to interact with Taptic Engine (iOS 9) directly, but there is a private method. You should not use it in App Store applications.

Comment: This method only can "play" the custom pattern when the app is at the foreground. My question is a pattern associate with user notification, but not play a vibration when the app is at foreground.

Comment: Yes, It's only work, when app in background and foreground.
function application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: it may or may not call that method. If a user has disabled background updating then the method is never called,
And it's not possible to create custom vibration pattern when app in terminated state.

Comment: This answer is not related to my question.

Comment: What is the way to interact with the Taptic Engine directly?  It may be helpful for an internal project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. In the below code you can get different types of vibrations with audio and without audio. make sure that you have imported these (import AudioToolbox, import AVFoundation)

```
if(selectedRow == 0){
          AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1304))
        }else if(selectedRow == 1){
             AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1329))
        }else if(selectedRow == 2){
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1301))
        }else if(selectedRow == 3){
           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1027))
        }else if(selectedRow == 4){
           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1028))
        }else if(selectedRow == 5){
            let alert = SystemSoundID(1011)
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(alert, nil)
        }else if(selectedRow == 6){
           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1333))
        }else if(selectedRow == 7){
           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(4095))
        }
```